# Regex Expression working in Notepad++ but not Java

Tags: java, regex

Okay, so i'm working on a problem I'd rather solve with regex, I test most of my regex expressions in Notepad++, This has worked fine after a few tweaks such as double escaping some things for java, However this regex expression throws an exception when run in java, however it runs in Notepad++ just fine, the idea if this code is to be able to mention a different player in the game with a highlighted name.

tldr; I'm trying to replace the first occurrence of a specific name in a message

I've tried looking around for a while but i haven't found a solution, so i thought i might as well ask here.

p.getName() simply returns a string (the players name)

```java
String newmessage = message.replaceFirst("(?i)" + Pattern.quote(p.getName()) + "((?(?=\\s)|('|,|!))|$)", color + p.getName() + Color.toString(Color.getLastColorOf(message)));
```

However executing the code throws this exception
`...at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_202]
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 15
(?i)\QTauCubed\E((?(?=\s)|('|,))|$)
               ^
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]...`

And I'm not sure  what it wants me to do, I don't see how this is not valid regex

This is the regex for Notepad++

```
(?i)Name((?(?=\s)|('|,|!))|$)
```

The above will match

```
Name's r
Name
Name test
Name,
Name!
```

But will not match

```
Nametest
```

That is what I intended it to do.

Comment: Did you check the Java regex documentation? Regex processors are not all alike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vote for just using the pattern `\bName\b` along with `String#replaceFirst`:

```
String input = "Rename here is a Name and here is the same Name again.";
input = input.replaceFirst("\\bName\\b", "blah");
System.out.println(input);
```

This prints:

```
Rename here is a blah and here is the same Name again.
```

Comment: I'm now getting the error:
`Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 19
(?i)\bTauCubed\b((?(?=\s)|('|,|!))|$)
                   ^
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]`
After changing that to (`"(?i)\\b" + p.getName() + "\\b((?(?=\\s)|('|,|!))|$)"`)

Comment: You do realize that what you are running has no resemblance to my answer, right?

Comment: Nevermind, I was thinking of quotes (dow) Perfect, Thanks for your time.